# What is the point of using "white noise" term in maths?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, noise

I've been studying on my master thesis about "Stochastic Differential Equations". Since I'm new to this topic, I couldn't understand the relation between "white noise" and mathematics. I searched about it. I guess it's actually related to sound or signals. But why are we using "noise" or "white noise" terms in maths if they really are related to sound? What is the point of using a term about sound in maths?

Edit : And why are we using "noise" term to denote random terms? (Like in the introduction part of Stochastic Differential Equations). Can't we just use like "random term" instead of "noise"?

Comment: It's important to try to model chaotic situations mathematically, white noise is the simplest source of "random" behavior.  Such situations arise all over the place, in finance, in percolation theory,  in the study of the heat equation, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding the term "noise" does not refer to sound in general. Of course in the specific case of sound it can be, but in my opinion its meaning lies more in a more general notion of an additional observation that makes the information you are really interested in more unclear. Like the static noise from a radio when you try to understand the news. Or in SDE, $dX_t = f(t)dt  + dB_t$, where $f$ is the information and Brownian motion is the noise. Mainly, the trajectory of $X_t$ would follow $f(t)$, but there is a random effect that pushes the "observable" information away from the real information by a whirring, or "noise".

To answer to your edit: In fact, the description "random term" is used when you speak about SDEs, due to the fact that the randomness comes only from $B_t$. But since the noise in reality is such pure randomness to our human senses and minds, it is reasonable to introduce it as notion for such random terms. Moreover, it is convenient to have the notion of "noise" attached to this specific topic, such that it exists separated from the in fact really general notion"random term".

Comment: Yeah, this is how it is interpreted in Economics. It is a particular type of noise that makes a given information/signals unclear. There are other types of "noise" that can obscure signals, but white noise is a particularly convenient to work with mathematically.

Comment: @Mdoc So, since "noise" term makes signals or audio unclear, we use it to denote unclear information of observations in maths. But we don't use any other word rather than "noise" just like it is being used in audio or signals. Am I right?

Comment: That's right. And that's why you often read in economics or finance about "noisy signals," which is information about the object that you want to learn (say future dividends) but which is imperfect, that is, does not reveal the true value perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of very good math comes out of applications, in this case to signal processing, and it's entirely appropriate to take terminology from the application.  Certainly better than just making up a word out of the blue.

Comment: So understandable why it's called noise when first signal processing applications were audio. But why colors of noise. Was it just because of the pun on Brownian?

Comment: @Ahusain, that's not really a math question, but more of an English and science of color question. See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/249562/57024 , for example.